# In XSLT 2.0 inside of a predicate how can I compare an attribute that has a namespace?

Tags: xslt

I have the following partial xpath expression

```
IAAXML:party[@xsi:type='IAAXML:Organization']
```

My source XML is:

```
<IAAXML:party xsi:type="IAAXML:Organization">
```

With the namespace declared as such:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

I get the following error:

```
The operand types are not compatible for the = operator
```

How do I do a compare on that attribute using the namespace?

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't simply a namespace issue but rather that the `xsi:type` attribute may get special handling in XSLT 2.0.  What happens if you try: `IAAXML:party[string(@xsi:type) = 'IAAXML:Organization']`? For an ordinary attribute with a namespace, the syntax you used should be just fine.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm unable to reproduce this issue in Altova. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Awesome JLRishe.  That fixed my problem.  Thanks you!  If you want, make it an answer and I'll accept.  I'm using the "IBM processor for XSLT 2.0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JLRishe has essentially given you the answer, but I'll amplify it. The `xsi:type` attribute is of type QName. In a schema-aware processor, your comparison is therefore a typed comparison between a QName and a string, which for very good reasons isn't allowed. After all, your application logic shouldn't really depend on the fact that the source document uses the namespace prefix IAAXML rather than some other prefix of the author's choosing. Given that you've got a type-aware processor, it would be better to do a QName comparison:

```
[@xsi:type = QName("http://the-iaaxml-namespace/", "Organization")]
```

Comment: Thank you for expounding.  So to clarify, is xsi:type treated specially or would the same be true for foo:bar?  Thanks.

Comment: From this point of view xsi:type is treated the same as any other attribute of type xs:QName. The difference is that xsi:type is implicitly declared in every schema, and is implicitly allowed on every element.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Kay more thoroughly explained the cause of this issue, but as I conjectured, certain processors treat `xsi:type` attributes as references to a schema type (which, as Michael clarified, are identified by their  QName).  So that's why the processor won't let you just compare it against a string value.  Assuming you are using the same namespace prefix for that type's namespace in both your source document and in that string value, it sounds like this works (and should work on any processor):

```
IAAXML:party[string(@xsi:type) = 'IAAXML:Organization']
```

But Michael's suggestion to use the QName with the namespace URI would be more a more robust approach in a schema-aware processor such as yours.