# Match an element with an xsi:type attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file which contains the following:

```
<contents id="MLC1" name="Requirement1" uri="C:\abc.txt" xsi:type="requirement:Requirement" type="">
<contents id="GO1" name="Goal1" uri="C:\abc.txt" xsi:type="goal:Goal">
```

I am trying to match all the  element within my XML file, which has the attribute `xsi:type="requirement:Requirement"` so that I can add a new attribute called "label" to it. This is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="//contents[@type='requirement:Requirement']">
    <contents>
        <xsl:attribute name="label">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </contents>
</xsl:template>
```

I have already declared `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in my stylesheet, but it seems that it is unable to match anything. I am suspecting it is because there is also another attribute "type" in the original xml which does not have the xsi namespace. Does anyone has any suggestion what should I use to match this element correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, make your input XML document well-formed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <contents id="MLC1" name="Requirement1" uri="C:\abc.txt" 
            xsi:type="requirement:Requirement" type=""/>
  <contents id="GO1" name="Goal1" uri="C:\abc.txt" xsi:type="goal:Goal"/>
</root>
```

**Then, be sure to use the `xsi` namespace prefix on `type`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="//contents[@xsi:type='requirement:Requirement']">
    <contents>
      <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>        
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </contents>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Then you'll get the following output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     label="Requirement1">MLC1Requirement1C:\abc.txtrequirement:Requirement</contents>
```

Comment: Alright, I actually tried this using java 7 built in XSLT parser which should be using Xalan. Trying with JLRishe's answer give me an exception  javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(QName, [literal-expr(dk.dtu.imm.red.specificationelements.requirement), literal-expr(Requirement)])'.. Trying it with the XSLT 1.0 Solution does not match any result. I will try to find out if it works for other XSLT parser (eg. Saxon) and post here again with my findings.

Comment: I followed the XSLT Test examples given from Saxon guide ( S9APIExamples.java) and it works fine with the XSLT 1.0 Solution, so I'll use that one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you will need to use the namespace prefix to select the attribute correctly:

```
<xsl:template match="//contents[@xsi:type='requirement:Requirement']">
```

If you're using a schema aware XSLT processor, the `xsi:type` attribute can have a special meaning and will need to be treated accordingly. [See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632554/in-xslt-2-0-inside-of-a-predicate-how-can-i-compare-an-attribute-that-has-a-name), but essentially you need to do:

```
<xsl:template match='//contents[@xsi:type = 
     QName("http://requirement/namespace/url/goes/here/", "Requirement")]'>
```

Comment: XSLT 2.0 doesn't give special meaning to `xsi:type`, XSD validation does.

Comment: I get an error, because the type of `xsi:type` ist not `QName`. It works with`<xsl:template match='//contents[fn:resolve-QName(@xsi:type, .) eq fn:QName("http://requirement/namespace/url/goes/here", "Requirement")]'>`.